# select image from gallery and camera and paste in image view which is in table view

Tags: swift3

I want to select image from gallery and camera and show it in imageview in tableview custom cell. Can I select 3 images from gallery and use camera photo and show in different image view?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can select Multiple Images from Gallery using this awesome library [DKImagePickerController](https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController)

You can use the following code on `UIButton` Action

```
var arrImage : [UIImage] = [UIImage]()


@IBAction func btnMultipleImage(_ sender: UIButton) {
    arrImageURL.removeAll()

    multiplePicker.delegate = self
    //multiplePicker.allowMultipleTypes = false
    multiplePicker.assetType = .allPhotos
    multiplePicker.maxSelectableCount = 4



    multiplePicker.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in
        for asset in assets {
            asset.fetchOriginalImageWithCompleteBlock({ (image, info) in
                    //info[PHImageFileURLKey]
                print(image!)
                self.arrImage.append(image!)
            })
        }
    }
    self.present(self.multiplePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now use this `arrImage` to show the images in TableView cell like

```
let image = arrImage[indexPath.row]
cell.imgView.image = image
```

Hope this helps.